# OpenGL depth test against cleared depth not as I expected (moderngl)

Tags: python, glsl, vertex-shader, depth-testing, python-moderngl

I am rendering a quad to a blank screen with its depth first cleared to (0.25). The depth of each vertex is set equal to its y coordinate, and it is a rectangle ranging from (-.5, -.5) to (.5, .5), so I would expect that the depth test (set to '>'), would obscure the bottom quarter of the quad, but instead, I see the entire quad on the screen. Based on my vertex shader code, I would expect that the depths of the vertices are -.5 and .5, so the bottom quarter where the depth is <.25 is what I would expect to fail the depth test, but this is not what I see. And, if I switch the depth test to '<', instead of showing only the bottom quarter, I see none of it. My program is as below:

```
import moderngl as gl
import numpy as np
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
pg.display.set_mode((800, 600), pg.DOUBLEBUF | pg.OPENGL)
context = gl.create_context(require=430)


bright_program = context.program(vertex_shader='''
#version 330
in vec2 position;
in vec3 in_color;
out vec3 out_color;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, position.y, 1.0);
    out_color = vec3(in_color);
}
''', fragment_shader='''
#version 330
in vec3 out_color;
layout(location=0) out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    fragColor = vec4(out_color, 1.0);
}
''')
buffer = context.buffer(np.array([-.5, -.5, 1, 1, 1,
    .5, -.5, 1, 0, 1,
    .5, .5, 1, 1, 0,
    -.5, -.5, 1, 1, 1,
    .5, .5, 1, 1, 0,
    -.5, .5, 0, 1, 1], dtype='float32'))
vao = context.vertex_array(bright_program, ((buffer, '2f4 3f4', 'position', 'in_color'),))
context.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
context.depth_func = '>'

clock = pg.time.Clock()
def render():
    r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
    context.clear(r, g, b, 1, 0.25)
    vao.render()

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(24)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
    render()
    pg.display.flip()

pg.quit()
```

Then, additionally, if I change the depth in the `.clear` line to 0.5, the two blend functions show the top and bottom halves of the quad, instead of all or nothing as I would expect. It seems like the depth of the entire screen is instead ranging from 0 to 1, rather than the depth of the top and bottom edges of the quad being +-.5. So why aren't the depths of the quad's vertices the +-.5 values I expect when it reaches the depth test? Does it have something to do with normalized device coords, even though I'm setting the w component of `gl_Position` to 1?

Answer (score 1):

If you do the math (basic interval mapping) then you'd see that you'd indeed see the whole quad because all of its fragments depths are greater than or equal to `0.25`.

The default OpenGL depth *range* is from `0` to `1` and you are clearing it to `0.25`. And the NDC z range that gets mapped to this depth range is `[-1..+1]`.

The following "ASCII art" code block should show the two linear intervals (depth range and your quad's z value):

```
depth range:   0 x . . 1
                 ^
                 |
quad z value: -1 y . z 1
```

- `x` should depict the depth value `0.25` (every dot is in steps of `0.25` here).
- `y` should depict your quad's z value of `-0.5`
- `z` is your quad z value of `+0.5`
- every tick in the lower "quad z value" interval is in steps of `0.5`

The ASCII "arrow" from `y` to `x` should indicate that your quad's z value of `-0.5` gets mapped to the depth value of `0.25`. Therefore, every quad's z value larger than that will also get mapped to a depth value larger than `0.25`.